# Upper and lower bounds for the Grothendieck inequality

Tags: inequality, hilbert-spaces

**The Grothendieck inequality** states that there is a universal constant ${\displaystyle K_{G}}$ with the following property. If $M_{i,j}$ is an $n$ by $n$ (real or complex) matrix with
$$\left|\sum_{i,j}^{ }M_{i,j}s_{i}t_{j}\right|\le1$$
for all (real or complex) numbers $s_i, t_j$ of absolute value at most $1$, then
$$\left|\sum_{i,j}^{ }M_{i,j}\left\langle S_{i},T_{j}\right\rangle \right|\le K_{G}$$
for all vectors $S_i, T_j$ in the unit ball $B(H)$ of a (real or complex) Hilbert space $H$.

It's known that the sequences $K_{G}^{\mathbb R}(d)$ and $K_{G}^{\mathbb C}(d)$ are increasing,moreover the bounds are given by:

> $$\frac{\pi}{2}\le K_{G}^{\mathbb R}(d)\le\sinh\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)$$

The proof of this claim is from a paper of Grothendieck,unfortunately I have not found it.

Can someone prove the inequality using the same approach as Grothendieck's?

Comment: It's a little technical.  But the explanation in Pisier, G. _Factorization of linear operators and geometry of Banach spaces_, Providence, RI: American Mathematical Society, 1986. is pretty clear and close to Grothendieck's.  The bounds can be improved. I found the paper by Krevine cited by the WIkipedia page hard to read.  I have checked the claimed $1.67..$ lower bound of A. M. Davje for $K_R$.

Comment: @  kimchi lover,I'm kinda sure that the question will not get any answer,wish I asked a crab,then I would get thousands of upvotes. the realistic fact of here.